# What is the name parameter in pubspec.yaml file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've used the package called **rename** to change my app name and it is changed successfully. However, I can see in the file **pubspec.yaml** the first parameter in the file is like this:

```
name: oldname
```

Is this parameter in *pubspec.yaml* effecting anything in the app?

I also still have the packages addresses is written as below on each page in my library:

```
import 'package:oldname/Pages/BasePage.dart';
import 'package:oldname/Globals.dart';
```

How can I change the old name here to the new one, and should I? Or this is not affecting anything that will actually be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name parameter in the *pubspec.yaml* file is used to specify the name of your Flutter project or package. It is a required field and must be unique within the Dart package repository.

If you change the name parameter in your *pubspec.yaml* file then you also need to change the statement from

```
import 'package:oldname/Pages/BasePage.dart';
import 'package:oldname/Globals.dart';
```

to

```
import 'package:newn_name/Pages/BasePage.dart';
import 'package:new_name/Globals.dart';
```

If you want to rename your project, I recommend you to use the *[rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename)* package.

It will change the app name. Then you can rename the 'name' in the *pubspec.yaml* file and then change all the import statements with find and replace.
It's not mandatory, but it's good to change it to the name of your app. Here is how you can easily change it with find and replace tool.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Mac) to open the "Find and Replace in Path" dialog.
2. In the "Find" field, enter the old app name (e.g., import 'package:old_app_name).
3. In the "Replace with" field, enter the new app name (e.g., import 'package:new_app_name).

Make sure the "File mask" field is set to *.dart to search only in Dart files.

4. Choose the "Directory" scope and ensure that the root directory of your project is selected.
5. Click on the "Find" button to show the search results.
6. Review the changes, and if everything looks good, click on the Replace All.

Comment: many thanks, I used this package, I managed through it to change the bundle id and the app name that is displayed to end user. however the name parameter in the pubspec.yaml and the import statements isn't changed. is it mandatory to change it or I can leave it as it is? and if it is mandatory, is there automated way or I have to go through each line?

Comment: It's not mandatory but it's good to change it to the name of your app. I have edited my answer and also added a way to easily edit all the names @MarkNugromentry

Comment: No it's not generated with chatgpt

Comment: @AkshitTyagi  You mean unlike [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695881/471272) which you deleted after I warned you about it?

Comment: @tchrist I am new to stack overflow and to be honest, in that answer I took 40% from chatgpt, then corrected it and then I read your article that you shared. But this one is totally written by me. Maybe you can check it with a AI text generator detector tool